# Having trouble sorting numbers with only if else statments

Tags: c++, if-statement, int, conditional-statements

For this assignment my professor tasked me with creating a program that asks the user to input 3 integer numbers and prints them out in order from bigger to smaller.
Ex: input is 10, 4, 6    the output should be  10, 6, 4 
I am only allowed to use if else statements and this is what I have so far but when I compile it says my variable position_1 - position_3 are not initiallized and I am also having trouble on my output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
int position_1;
int position_2;
int position_3;

cout<<"Please enter your first integer value"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Please enter your second integer value"<<endl;
cin>>y;
cout<<"Finally enter your third integer value"<<endl;
cin>>z;

if(x>y && x>z)
x=position_1;
else if (x  >y && x < z)
x=position_2;
else if (x <y && x > z)
x=position_2;
else 
x=position_3;

if(y>x && y>z)
y=position_1;
else if (y >x && y < z)
y=position_2;
else if (y <x && y > z)
y=position_2;
else 
y=position_3;

if(z>x && z>y)
z=position_1;
else if (z >x && z < y)
z=position_2;
else if (z <x && z > y)
z=position_2;
else 
z=position_3;

cout<<position_1 + " " + position_2 + " " + position_3.\n;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have written the assignments the other way round.  You probably wanted to say

```
position_1 = x;
```

instead of

```
x=position_1;
```

and so on...

Comment: However now I get an error (31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>  name_sort3.cpp

Comment: @JamesRnepJacobs Your `cout` doesn't make sense: `position_3.\n;` (4th line from end).

Comment: I fixed that part to make it cout<<position_1 + position_2 + position_3; however it is saying I am missing a ; before the bracket and i dont see how

Comment: @JamesRnepJacobs I'm not sure about that, but a closer look at your code suggests that it contains logical errors and wouldn't do the expected (i.e. sort) for varied inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely to work... I didn't try it, because I have some problems with compiler, but I think it should work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x, y, z;
int position_1, position_2, position_3;

cout<<"Please enter your first integer value"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Please enter your second integer value"<<endl;
cin>>y;
cout<<"Finally enter your third integer value"<<endl;
cin>>z;

if(x>y&&x>z){
    position_1 = x;
    if(y>z){
        position_2 = y;
        position_3 = z;
    }
    else{
        position_2 = z;
        position_3 = y;
    }
}
else if(y>x&&y>z){
    position_1 = y;
    if(x>z){
        position_2 = x;
        position_3 = z;
    }
    else{
        position_2 = z;
        position_3 = x;
    }
}
else if(z>x&&z>y){
    position_1 = z;
    if(y>x){
        position_2 = y;
        position_3 = x;
    }
    else{
        position_2 = x;
        position_3 = y;
    }
}

cout << position_1 << " " << position_2 << " " << position_3;

cin.get();
cin.get();

}
```

I haven't programmed in c++ for almost a year, but I don't think this works in c++

```
cout<<position_1 + " " + position_2 + " " + position_3.\n;
```

as far as I can remember that should look like this:

```
cout<<position_1 << " " << position_2 << " " << position_3 <<"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
if(x>=y && x>=z)
{
  position_1 = x;
  if(y>=z)
  {
    position_2 = y;
    position_3 = z;
  }
  else
  {
    position_3 = y;
    position_2 = z;
  }
}
else
{
  if (x>=y || x>=z)
  {
    position_2 = x;
    if(y>=z)
    {
      position_1 = y;
      position_3 = z;
    }
    else
    {
      position_3 = y;
      position_1 = z;
    }
  }
  else
  { 
    position_3 = x;
    if(y>=z)
    {
      position_1 = y;
      position_2 = z;
    }
    else
    {
      position_2 = y;
      position_1 = z;
    }
  }
}

cout<<position_1<<" "<<position_2<<" "<<position_3<<"\n";
```